# Split data in half based on dates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'd like to split my data in half by year(s). So below in my sample data I need the result to be two separate dataframes, one with the first 50% of each of the years and the other half in the other one. Additional condition is that is that the 50% needs to be based on column 'LG'.

Can anyone help me with this?

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'LG' : ('AR1', 'AR1', 'AR1', 'AR1', 'AR1', 'AR1', 'PO1',  'PO1', 'AR1', 'AR1', 'PO1', 'PO1'),
     'Date': ('2011-1-1', '2011-3-1',  '2011-4-1', '2011-2-1', '2012-1-1', '2012-2-1', '2012-1-1', '2012-2-1', '2013-1-1', '2013-2-1', '2013-1-1', '2013-2-1'),
     'Year': (2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013)})

pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

**df:**

```
         Date   LG  Year
0  2011-01-01  AR1  2011
1  2011-03-01  AR1  2011
2  2011-04-01  AR1  2011
3  2011-02-01  AR1  2011
4  2012-01-01  AR1  2012
5  2012-02-01  AR1  2012
6  2012-01-01  PO1  2012
7  2012-02-01  PO1  2012
8  2013-01-01  AR1  2013
9  2013-02-01  AR1  2013
10 2013-01-01  PO1  2013
11 2013-02-01  PO1  2013
```

Comment: `df['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)` is a slow way of saying `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`.

Comment: edited per you remark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the frame in half after grouping on `Year` and `LG`.  Basic idea is to find location in group that is less than 50% of the group size

**Code:**

```
# group by 'Year' and 'LG'
idx = ['Year', 'LG']

# build a grouper
group_by = df.groupby(idx, as_index=False)

# need frame to re-expand the group size
df1 = df.set_index(idx)
df1['g_size'] = group_by.size()

# find the rows in the top half of respective group
top_half = (group_by.cumcount() / df1.g_size.values).values < 0.5

# build new data frames
top = df.loc[top_half]
bot = df.loc[~top_half]
```

**Code for sorting on Date:**

If the frame needs to be sorted by date before splitting, but do not want the sort to be in the original DataFrame...

```
# group by 'Year' and 'LG'
idx = ['Year', 'LG']

# sort by date
df1 = df.sort('Date')

# build a grouper
group_by = df1.groupby(idx, as_index=False)

# Need to set the index to match the result of groupby.size()
df1 = df1.set_index(idx)
df1['g_size'] = group_by.size()

# find the rows in the top half of respective group
top_half = (group_by.cumcount() / df1.g_size.values).values < 0.5

# build new data frames
top = df1.loc[top_half].drop('g_size', axis=1).reset_index()
bot = df1.loc[~top_half].drop('g_size', axis=1).reset_index()
```

**Test Code:**

```
print(df)
print('-- top')
print(top)
print('-- bot')
print(bot)
print('--')
```

**Sorted Results:**

```
        Date   LG  Year
0   2011-1-1  AR1  2011
1   2011-3-1  AR1  2011
2   2011-4-1  AR1  2011
3   2011-2-1  AR1  2011
4   2012-1-1  AR1  2012
5   2012-2-1  AR1  2012
6   2012-1-1  PO1  2012
7   2012-2-1  PO1  2012
8   2013-1-1  AR1  2013
9   2013-2-1  AR1  2013
10  2013-1-1  PO1  2013
11  2013-2-1  PO1  2013
-- top
   Year   LG      Date
0  2011  AR1  2011-1-1
1  2011  AR1  2011-2-1
2  2012  AR1  2012-1-1
3  2012  PO1  2012-1-1
4  2013  AR1  2013-1-1
5  2013  PO1  2013-1-1
-- bot
   Year   LG      Date
0  2011  AR1  2011-3-1
1  2011  AR1  2011-4-1
2  2012  AR1  2012-2-1
3  2012  PO1  2012-2-1
4  2013  AR1  2013-2-1
5  2013  PO1  2013-2-1
```

**Test Data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'LG': ('AR1', 'AR1', 'AR1', 'AR1', 'AR1', 'AR1',
           'PO1', 'PO1', 'AR1', 'AR1', 'PO1', 'PO1'),
    'Date': ('2011-1-1', '2011-3-1', '2011-4-1', '2011-2-1', '2012-1-1',
             '2012-2-1', '2012-1-1', '2012-2-1', '2013-1-1', '2013-2-1',
             '2013-1-1', '2013-2-1'),
    'Year': (2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013,
             2013, 2013, 2013)
})
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Comment: Thanks, one issue though. AR1 in 2011 is not split up correctly. 2011-2-1 is in group 'bottom' and 2011-3-1 in group 'top'. How come?

Comment: Oh, you want it sorted?  You didn't show any example output, so i didn't assume.  Let me whip something up...

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I meant first 50% of the years as in dates, not in column as shown. Thanks though

Comment: How does that look?